# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException' in my "game"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following and online course and got stock because even by following the step (or maybe I missed some ? ) i get and error. I made several search on google and here but since i'm new to IOS development, even with answer from others, i can relate to my issue..

here is the error:

```
2015-06-12 23:03:17.477 Pirate Game[6511:1193126] -[RBTile setWeapon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78830dc0
2015-06-12 23:03:17.481 Pirate Game[6511:1193126] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RBTile setWeapon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78830dc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00874746 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x004fda97 objc_exception_throw + 44
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0087c705 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
3   CoreFoundation                      0x007c3287 ___forwarding___ + 1047
4   CoreFoundation                      0x007c2e4e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
5   Pirate Game                         0x00014a94 -[RBFactory tiles] + 388
6   Pirate Game                         0x00011c6f -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 143
7   UIKit                               0x00d97da4 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 771
8   UIKit                               0x00d98095 -[UIViewController view] + 35
9   UIKit                               0x00c89e85 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 66
10  UIKit                               0x00c8a34c -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 287
11  UIKit                               0x00c8a648 -[UIWindow _orderFrontWithoutMakingKey] + 49
12  UIKit                               0x00c989b6 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 80
13  UIKit                               0x00c2ded8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3217
14  UIKit                               0x00c31422 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1639
15  UIKit                               0x00c4a93e __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 59
16  UIKit                               0x00c3004a -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 155
17  FrontBoardServices                  0x031d6c9e __37-[FBSWorkspace clientEndTransaction:]_block_invoke_2 + 71
18  FrontBoardServices                  0x031d672f __40-[FBSWorkspace _performDelegateCallOut:]_block_invoke + 54
19  FrontBoardServices                  0x031e8d7c __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 30
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00796050 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
21  CoreFoundation                      0x0078b963 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 195
22  CoreFoundation                      0x0078b7bb __CFRunLoopRun + 2715
23  CoreFoundation                      0x0078aa5b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0078a88b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
25  UIKit                               0x00c2fa02 -[UIApplication _run] + 571
26  UIKit                               0x00c33106 UIApplicationMain + 1526
27  Pirate Game                         0x000148da main + 138
28  libdyld.dylib                       0x02c00ac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

So what i could understand from my search, is that i'm trying to send something that is not the same type. I have the same problem with all 3 custom class.

```
//
//  RBFactory.m
//  Pirate Game
//
//  Created by Richard Berube on 2015-06-06.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Richard Berube. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RBFactory.h"
#import "RBTile.h"

@implementation RBFactory

-(NSArray *)tiles{


    RBTile *tile1 = [[RBTile alloc] init];
    tile1.story = @"Captain, we need a fearless leader such as you to undertake a voyage. You must stop the evil pirate Boss before he steals any more plunder. Would you like a blunted sword to get started?";
    tile1.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PirateStart.png"];
    CCWeapon *bluntedSword = [[CCWeapon alloc]init];
    bluntedSword.name = @"Blunted sword";
    bluntedSword.damage = 12;
    NSLog(@"%@", bluntedSword);
    tile1.weapon = bluntedSword;
    tile1.actionButtonName =@"Take the sword";
```

I tested with breakpoint and the crash occure

```
tile1.weapon = bluntedSword;
```

NSLog return:

```
2015-06-12 23:03:14.602 Pirate Game[6511:1193126] <CCWeapon: 0x786a6f50>
```

here is the tile class

```
//
//  RBTile.h
//  Pirate Game
//
//  Created by Richard Berube on 2015-06-06.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Richard Berube. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CCWeapon.h"
#import "CCArmor.h"

@interface RBTile : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *story;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *backgroundImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *actionButtonName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CCWeapon *weapon;
@property (strong, nonatomic) CCArmor *armor;
@property (nonatomic) int healthEffect;

@end
```

The .m file is empty

```
//
//  RBTile.m
//  Pirate Game
//
//  Created by Richard Berube on 2015-06-06.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Richard Berube. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RBTile.h"

@implementation RBTile

@end
```

And the last one is the custom class, one of them actualy, because all 3 are causing the same issue..

```
//
//  CCWeapon.h
//  Pirate Game
//
//  Created by Richard Berube on 2015-06-10.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Richard Berube. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CCWeapon : NSObject

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) int damage;

@end
```

A little help would be really apreciated! i'm now stock since 2 days.. i could start over all the video (online course) but that won't teach me how to debug ..

Maybe the last usefull info could be that i used Xcode 6.3.1

THanks !

update 1 : The final project is this one 
https://github.com/codecoalition/Pirate-Adventure-Assignment/tree/master/Pirate%20Adventure

my RBtile is the CCtile in the github project

update 2: here is my viewcontroler

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Pirate Game
//
//  Created by Richard Berube on 2015-06-06.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Richard Berube. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RBFactory.h"
#import "RBTile.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    RBFactory *factory = [[RBFactory alloc]init];
    self.tiles = [factory tiles];
    self.character = [factory character];
    self.currentPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [self updateTile];
    [self updateButtons];
    [self updateCharacterStatsForArmor:nil withWeapons:nil withHealthEffect:0];
}

-(void)updateTile{
    RBTile *tileModel = [[self.tiles objectAtIndex:self.currentPoint.x] objectAtIndex:self.currentPoint.y];
    self.storyLabel.text = tileModel.story;
    self.backgroundImageView.image = tileModel.backgroundImage;
    self.healthLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.character.health];
    self.damageLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.character.damage];
    self.armorLabel.text = self.character.armor.name;
    self.weaponLabel.text = self.character.weapon.name;
    [self.actionButton setTitle:tileModel.actionButtonName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)actionButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    RBTile *tile = [[self.tiles objectAtIndex:self.currentPoint.x] objectAtIndex:self.currentPoint.y];
    [self updateCharacterStatsForArmor:tile.armor withWeapons:tile.weapon withHealthEffect:tile.healthEffect];
    [self updateTile];
}

- (IBAction)northButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.currentPoint = CGPointMake(self.currentPoint.x, self.currentPoint.y +1);
    [self updateButtons];
    [self updateTile];
}

- (IBAction)southButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.currentPoint = CGPointMake(self.currentPoint.x, self.currentPoint.y -1);
    [self updateButtons];
    [self updateTile];

}

- (IBAction)eastButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.currentPoint = CGPointMake(self.currentPoint.x + 1, self.currentPoint.y);
    [self updateButtons];
    [self updateTile];
}

- (IBAction)westButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.currentPoint = CGPointMake(self.currentPoint.x - 1, self.currentPoint.y);
    [self updateButtons];
    [self updateTile];
}

- (IBAction)restartButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
}

-(void)updateButtons{
    self.westButton.hidden = [self tilesExistAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.currentPoint.x -1, self.currentPoint.y)];
    self.eastButton.hidden = [self tilesExistAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.currentPoint.x+1, self.currentPoint.y)];
    self.northButton.hidden = [self tilesExistAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.currentPoint.x, self.currentPoint.y+1)];
    self.southButton.hidden = [self tilesExistAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.currentPoint.x, self.currentPoint.y-1)];
}

-(BOOL)tilesExistAtPoint:(CGPoint)point{
    if (point.y >= 0 && point.x >=0 && point.x < [self.tiles count] && point.y < [[self.tiles objectAtIndex:point.x] count]) {
        return NO;
    }
    else{
        return YES;
    }
}

-(void)updateCharacterStatsForArmor:(CCArmor *)armor withWeapons:(CCWeapon *)weapon withHealthEffect:(int)healtEffect{

    if (armor != nil ) {
        self.character.health = self.character.health - self.character.armor.health +armor.health;
        self.character.armor = armor;
    }
    else if (weapon != nil){
        self.character.damage = self.character.damage - self.character.weapon.damage + weapon.damage;
        self.character.weapon = weapon;
    }
    else if (healtEffect != 0){
        self.character.health = self.character.health + healtEffect;
    }
    else {
        self.character.health = self.character.health + self.character.armor.health;
        self.character.damage = self.character.damage + self.character.weapon.damage;
    }
}

@end
```

Another update:

I was able to find with the breakpoint that some of my property are not showing up.. [image: tile1]

When in fact it should be like that:

[image: Should be like this]

So now i know that when i try to pass `tile1.weapon = bluntedSword;` it is not working because `tile1.weapon` do not exist. But if you look in my `RBTile.h` all my property are there..

Comment: Your code looks well. Could you post some more in `viewController` about how you init the instance var? Specially `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Juste updated it, the <viewController.m> does not seem to cause issue, i tested it with breakpoint as well and everything crash before getting to my updateTile method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following the same course, and my code is the same as yours, and it works. The `Tile.m` files is empty.

In recent Xcode versions, `synthesize` statements are not always necessary. Some rare cases, I think, still need them.

I think the reason you don't see the other properties in the debug window is because the code that creates them hasn't run yet.

Try commenting out the lines that related to `bluntedSword` and see if the other properties are set successfully, or if they also cause the app to crash.

Another thing to try, and I understand how silly it sounds, is to re-type the lines (not copy and paste) and related lines that are causing the problems. Sometimes this works, so it's worth trying.

Good luck!

Comment: I did use some comment to see if other property are set, i even created another class from scrach to see if i would set and it did not .. i'm kind of shock by all that. I even open 2 Xcode side by side to compare with the final project that we can find on github and all line (except the class name) are the same.

I know i could start over and rewrite them, but I keep trying because if i get the issue with one personal project and want to be able to solve it. 

And that we learn more (well i do) when we make mistake than when all go well :) . i am on that since 5 days in a row now haha

Comment: i will change my class for the same name as he did and try your suggestion to retype (and not copy past) to see if any different. i'll update in a couple of hours ! :)

Comment: ok.. so now.. i don't even belive it myself .. I did NOT change any code in any of my files, copied folder on my desktop, ran it from there and it worked !! 

I don't know how it is possible, to just making a copy of the entire folder in the same folder (MyUserName/app/) (the default folder where xcode save our project) did work! I guess it has something to do with file permission .. still don't know how it's possible .. unbelivable :O

Answer (score 0):

The root of the issue is this

> [RBTile setWeapon:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78830dc0

That is telling you that your `RBTile.weapon` property on the `RBTile` class does not have a setter. Please update your post with the `.m` file showing how you are creating the `weapon` property on the `RBTile`. Odds are you are declaring a getter and potentially forgetting the setter.

Your .m file is empty, which is causing the issue. The header file just defines a contract between an object using your class, and the implementation of the class in the .m file. You can think of it as a bridge of sorts between something using the class, and the actual implementation of the class.

At runtime, the game can't find an implementation of the property to work with, thus the reason why `unrecognized selector` is being thrown.

Comment: You were right about the issue, if you look i added some details and my property are there, but when `tile1` is init only the frist 3 property are initialise ..

Comment: I understand your point, but it is strange, in the source code from the course the `.m` is empty and i created another xcode project and even with `.m` empty, with init they are showing in console. In this case, even `@property (nonatomic) int healthEffect;` wich is not a custom class is not showing up..

Comment: It's been awhile since I wrote objective-c. Last time I wrote it, you were required to synthesize all of your properties in the .m file